# how can i make shell that run program when open vscode?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

Hi I just begin my linux back a few days ago. I get mini PC from my brother and i just try to use linux. My brother use this mini PC so there are vscode or other program. I wonder what he made so i try to review the code but somehow when i open the vscode, the program automatically run. I asked the reason to my brother but he didn't touch for a while so he said no idea. I want to make sure never make mistake like this again and it could be useful someday.

the program is ros2 based on cpp and there are alias in bashrc

```
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
source ~/ros2_ws/install/setup.bash

alias cw='cd ~/ros2_ws'
alias cs='cd ~/ros2_ws/src'
alias cm='cd ~/ros2_ws && colcon build --symlink-install --cmake-args -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON && source ~/.bashrc'
```

I know there are no information i really sorry and hope you understand

ofcoursely I expect program didn't run, again sorry about poor information